# how to create 2 dimensional array and store values at run time in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

i created two dimensional array with the following code. but i can not store value in the array. row and columns of array grows dynamically. can not predict before.

```
arr = Array.new {Array.new}
```

and can not do this type of things.....

```
arr[0][0] = "Ruby"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstraction over the standard array, like so

```
class MyArray < Array
    def [](idx)
        self.at(idx) ? self.at(idx) : self[idx] = []
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could use a Hash whose `default_proc` creates a new array at the specified index. OR a hash whose keys are [row, column]. This would be the best option for large datasets as your operations would be in O(1) time.